# What is the data, meta_data part in AlphaVantage Api documentation

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

I am wondering what last sentence means,
I was looking at the example of using AlphaVantage API and didn't really understand that last line.
First time I thought it is saving that `ts.get_daily('GOOGL', 1)` result in `data` and `meta_data` variable but
I printed `data` and `meta_data` and they had different results.. Why is it so?

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
key = 'your key here'
ts = TimeSeries(key)
# Get json object with the daily data and another with  the call's metadata
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily('GOOGL', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the API response: "Meta Data" and "Time Series (Daily)"

The library is mapping `meta_data` to "Meta Data" and "Time Series (Daily)" to `data`

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-08-31",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-08-31": {
            "1. open": "125.2500",
            "2. high": "125.2500",
            "3. low": "123.0300",
            "4. close": "123.3100",
            "5. volume": "4827879"
        }
    }
}
```